# Building Boost 1.52 with non-standard location of MinGW

Tags: c++, boost, batch-file, mingw, bjam

I tried to build Boost from source for 64bit using MinGW (x64) but failed when creating the bjam.exe. Any pointer to help is appreciated. Thanks.

- Package: Boost 1.52.0 (download from sourceforge, C:\BoostSrc)
- Package: MinGW-w64 (4.7.2-x64 rubenvb, C:\MinGW\rubenvb-4.7.2-64)

I created the following batch file to ensure repeatable building, but things got wrong. I cannot build the bjam.exe with supplied batch file. I'm not using the supplied "bootstrap.bat" as the non-standard installation path of MinGW (I have multiple mingw sets), and I have no MSVC installed in my machine

```
SET BOOST_VER=boost_1_52_0
SET PATH_MINGW=C:\MinGW\rubenvb-4.7.2-64
SET PATH_BJAM=%~dp0\%BOOST_VER%\tools\build\v2\engine
SET PATH="%PATH_MINGW%\bin"
PUSHD "%PATH_BJAM%"

REM check path
mingw32-make -version

REM error below
build.bat mingw --toolset-root=%PATH_MINGW% --show-locate-target

SET PATH=%OPATH%
POPD
REM ... some more ...
```

Error message

gcc: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory

When I type the command directly from command prompt (set the path, go to location and invoke build.bat), it goes smoothly (with warnings which i think can be ignored)

Comment: Try `SET PATH=%PATH_MINGW%\bin;%PATH%` - you're leaving a lot of stuff off the path that really should be there (like `c:\windows\system32').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into build.bat located at BOOST_ROOT\tools\build\v2\engine, when supplying "mingw" as the toolset, the script by-passed the "guessing toolset" step and failed to define the variable "BOOST_JAM_TOOLSET_ROOT", leaving calls to gcc-related executables failed.

Now I changed the batch as follow

```
PUSHD "%PATH_BJAM%"
SET "PATH=%PATH_MINGW%\bin"

REM add the line below
SET "BOOST_JAM_TOOLSET_ROOT=%PATH_MINGW%\"

build.bat mingw --show-locate-target
SET PATH=%OPATH%
```

I manually set the BOOST_JAM_TOOLSET_ROOT variable from external batch file and this worked fine. Beware of the ending "\" character, as the build.bat inside append the path variable as this:

```
set "PATH=%BOOST_JAM_TOOLSET_ROOT%bin;%PATH%"
```

Thanks very much for any comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

This may solve your issue, but even if it doesn't it's a good idea to change it anyways.

Use a different variable name other than `PATH` as this is a built in and important windows environment variable, which MINGW may be relying on.

Comment: Along with what Bali C said, it is a good rule of thumb to prefix your batch variables.  I like to use `x` in front of my variables, another popular prefix is `var`.  That way you know that the variable you are referencing does not interfere with known standard environment variables and that they were created by you.  `set xPath=` or `set varPath=`

Comment: @Bali, I used the "Path" variable in "SET PATH=XXX" as I need Windows to find my CORRECT mingw32-make.exe (as I have multiple mingw). The set command is also invoked when direct input from command prompt, but that worked smoothly. I need it to be done at batch file.